# How do I create a generic function that dynamically executes any stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Environment:
EF Core and .Net Core 3.1

I’m trying to create a single  generic function that will dynamically run any stored procedure and can return anything.

```
public U ExecuteStoredProcedure(string spName, params SqlParameter[], T someGenericType)
```

Code:

```
public abstract class Repository<C, T> : IRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
{
    public DbContext Context { get; set; } = new C();

    public Repository()
    {
        Context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure(string spName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Any())
        {
            var paramNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                var name = param.ParameterName;
                if (param.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
                {
                    name = $"{param.ParameterName} OUT";
                }
                paramNames.Add(name);
            }
            
            var x = Context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw($"EXEC {spName} {String.Join(",", paramNames.ToArray())}", parameters);

            return x.ToList();
        }

        return Context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw($"EXEC {spName}").ToList();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you declare it like public IEnumerable<U> ExecuteStoredProcedure<U>(string spName, params SqlParameter[]) the caller would call it with repository.ExecuteStoredProcedure<double>("name", ...) where the "double" part is the caller choosing the type returned (or rather an IEnumerable<double> in this case). Youd need to change the code in the function, I cant speak to entity stuffs. Essentially the <U> between function name and parameters lets the caller send in a type argument.

Comment: You can make this change: `public U ExecuteStoredProcedure<U>(string spName, Func<IEnumerable<T>, U> project, params SqlParameter[] parameters)`. However, I don't expect this is what you want. You should read [ask] and then improve your question.

Comment: Are you sure it is wise to make such a generic procedure? Your DbContext represents your database, it contains all the tables, functionality to query data, and to add / update / remove items. Your database contains only some specific stored procedures, for example A, B, and C each with their specific parameters. In proper OO programming Your DbContext should publish only those stored procedures, since other procedures are not Supported. This way errors will be detected at compile time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't get an answer for this till now. Please check my approach below

1. For an efficient way of implementing this, you need to have a standard architecture for your stored procedures. Mainly return modes/types.
   As you we can have Output parameters, return a value or result sets as return types from a stored procedures. You can have a common method to handle all these returns. This is not too much. I suggest have a default table retuned which carry any errors or message to calling application. This must be last select statement executed in the SP. So that you can handle this table as N-1 th table in data set.
2. Now for handling all types of input parameters you can have a methods which can handle all usually used data types. This method can create the parameter array or collection required for calling SP.
3. On top of this if you configure all your SP's with its parameters along with data type in configuration again in a standard structure, you just need to iterate through this and set values for parameter collection creation. This also put into a common method.

Comments please.